# Highcharts - SetState (inactive) not working after redraw

Tags: highcharts

Consider the following toy example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javiermarquez/nhsvju24/)

```
 chart: {
    events: {
      render: myfunc
    }
  },
```

...

```
function myfunc() {
  var chart = this;

  chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
    s.setState('inactive', true);
  });
  chart.series[0].setState('hover');
}
```

The intended behavior is to set the state of the first series as **hover** while setting all other series as **inactive** after *load* and *redraw* events.

1. The code works as intended after *load*
2. However, it doesn't work after *redraw* (via the *select box*). After selecting an option in the box, the series are rendered as **normal** instead of as **inactive** UNLESS any series had been previously hovered. That is, the code works if you interact with any series AND THEN select an option in the box, but it doesn't work if you select an option in the box immediately after the loading without interacting on the series.

Surprisingly, after some inspection in the console, I noted that in any case the intended states are properly passed to the series object. **So, why the states are not properly rendered?**

*NOTE: In my actual application the *hovered* series is not necessarily the first one, but it varies depending on the output of other function. I'm aware that "*myfunc*" could be simplified in the current example, but for general purposes please suggest an answer keeping the basic structure if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing this issue, it seems that it is a regression after the last release.

In the previous version it used to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lbpvdwam/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.0/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.1.0/highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

I reported it on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13719

If you don't need any new features/bugfixes use the previous version as a temporary workaround.

Comment: @JavierMárquez please take a look at the GitHub thread - there is a new workaround available.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I just looked at it!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11750#issue-484166434) from HighChart's GitHub. In your case, HighCharts is correctly updating the series' state. However, while rendering it fails to set the proper opacity value associated with the `'inactive'` state. **The workaround is to explicitly set the opacity of the series** to the same value it should have in the `'inactive'` state.

```js
// F U N C T I O N   S E T   S T A T E
function myfunc() {
  var chart = this;

  chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
    //explicit opacity
    s.opacity = 0.2;
    s.setState('inactive', true);
  });
  chart.series[0].setState('hover');
}
```